# Why is the given array key not working in JSON_decode to decode the API response?

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to work with [this](https://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#ocean) API. An example of the JSON is:

```
{"ocean": {
  "distance": "0",
  "geonameId": 3411923,
  "name": "North Atlantic Ocean"
}}
```

My app takes user input using html like this:

```
        <label for="setLatOcean">Latitude (between -90 and 90):</label>
        <input type="number" id="setLatOcean" name="setLatOcean" min="-90" max="90">

        <label for="setLngOcean">Longitude (between -180 and 180):</label>
        <input type="number" id="setLngOcean" name="setLngOcean" min="-180" max="180">

        <label for="setRad">Radius(Optional but must be greater than zero if included):</label>
        <input type="number" id="setRad" name="setRad" min="0">

        <td align="center"><button id="btnRunOcean">Run</button></td>
```

Which goes to an ajax call:

```
$('#btnRunOcean').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getNearestOcean.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            lat: $('#setLatOcean').val(),
            lng: $('#setLngOcean').val(),
            radius:$('#setRad').val()
        },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                $('#txtDistance').html(result['data'][0]['distance']);
                $('#txtName').html(result['data'][0]['name']);

            }
        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // your error code
        }
    }); 

});
```

Which links to this php script(getNearestOcean.php):

```
<?php

    // remove for production

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='http://api.geonames.org/oceanJSON?formatted=true&lat=' . $_REQUEST['lat'] . '&lng=' 
. $_REQUEST['lng'] . '&radius=' . $_REQUEST['radius'] . '&username=flightltd&style=full';
    
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
    
        curl_close($ch);
    
        $decode = json_decode($result,true);    
    
        $output['status']['code'] = "200";
        $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
        $output['status']['description'] = "success";
        $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
        $output['data'] = $decode["ocean"];
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    
        echo json_encode($output); 
    
    ?>
```

Which should return the API data to this table:

```
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
             Distance from Ocean:
        </td>
        <td id="txtDistance">
            
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            Name of Ocean:
        </td>
        <td id="txtName">
            
        </td>

    </tr>            

</table>
```

But XAMPP throws an error saying

```
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "ocean" in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\geonamesExample\\geonamesSolution\\libs\\php\\getNearestOcean.php on line 27, referer: http://localhost/geonamesExample/geonamesSolution/
```

However, I was given the following example:

```
{"geonames": [{
  "continent": "EU",
  "capital": "Berlino",
  "languages": "de",
  "geonameId": 2921044,
  "south": 47.2701236047002,
  "isoAlpha3": "DEU",
  "north": 55.0583836008072,
  "fipsCode": "GM",
  "population": "82927922",
  "east": 15.0418156516163,
  "isoNumeric": "276",
  "areaInSqKm": "357021.0",
  "countryCode": "DE",
  "west": 5.8663152683722,
  "countryName": "Germania",
  "postalCodeFormat": "#####",
  "continentName": "Europa",
  "currencyCode": "EUR"
}]}
```

Which uses the script

```
<?php

    // remove for production

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?formatted=true&lang=' . $_REQUEST['lang'] . '&country=' . $_REQUEST['country'] . '&username=flightltd&style=full';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

And it works fine. How can I make getNearestOcean.php work? I've been looking at for hours and I have no idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't checked your code but `dataType: 'json'` makes jQuery (are you using jQuery?) encode/decode automatically. If you also do it yourself, it'll happen twice.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am using it but I was sent an example which works, then tasked with applying the same methods to other API's. The problem is the JSON files are all formatted slightly differently and the example is very specific.